# Connecting Oracle 8i and 11g from SSIS

Tags: ssis, oracle11g, oracle8i

I'm using SSIS to connect and pull data from Oracle 8i and 11g for my current project.
But I learned that oracle 11g driver is only compatible from 9i.

What is the most feasible solution to connect SSIS with both 11g and 8i?
Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading the 8i database would be the best solution but assuming that's not possible right now, I would write a script on the 8i server itself to export the data to flat files, then copy those flat files to the SSIS server and process them from there.

Comment: exporting the data from 8i is a good option. But there are 3 physically different oracle 8i database and out of that 2 are live. I think exporting data will be costly if my ETL runs everyday.

Comment: What does "costly" mean? The easiest way to see how well (or not) this works is to try it and see. You can export just a couple of tables on your test system first and then you'll have solid information to help you make a decision. And if you can't upgrade 8i because of money (I know that may not be your reason), it would be useful to track the time you spend on this task so that you can show your boss/customer some of the cost implications of staying with 8i.

Comment: The time taken for the tables to get exported was reasonable and we opted to go with the method you mentioned - dumping oracle data to text files. Thanks for your suggestion.